# How could Donald Menken fire Harry Osborn?

Tags: the-amazing-spider-man-2

In "The Amazing Spiderman 2" Norman Osbon, owner of Oscorp, hands over his company to his son Harry Osborn. Later in the movie, Harry is fired by Donald for "covering up the murder of Max".

- How could Donald fire Harry, the owner of Oscorp?
- If Donald really did have the power to fire him, why wait all this time? It seems he could have fired him for a variety of other reasons or even created false reasons.
- Firing him for covering up Max's "death" when Max was still at Oscorp (along with other secret projects) seems like a silly idea that could easily have backfired for Donald.

**Given the above, how could Donald fire Harry?**

Comment: Answer #1: There are MANY times that owners/founders get fired.  Happened to Bruce Wayne, too.  ;)  But seriously, an owner can be fired by his company's Board of Directors if it's in the best interest of the company.  And in the real world, it does happen.

Comment: In the same way [they fired Steve Jobs from Apple](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Steve-Jobs-fired-from-Apple).

Comment: Once a founder/owner cashes in and "goes public," they basically trade in the bulk of their ownership to the public in forms of stock shares, making it possible for a Board to dump them, if they get the backing of enough of a percentage of active shareholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, CEOs can and have been frequently fired by their company's Board of Directors.  Inc Magazine published a [list of 6 of the top CEO founders who have been fired from the companies they founded](https://www.inc.com/magazine/201606/inc-staff/ss/fired-founders.html), among them the founders of Apple, Etsy, Cisco and JetBlue.

Remember, Harry wasn't CEO for very long.  Menken didn't like the idea of having to answer to a boy, and he found a perfect opening to have his lone obstacle removed when the whole issue of Max Dillon arose.  While the movie shows Menken saying,

> In light of your deceptive criminal actions, you've been...  How do I
>   put this gently?  Fired.

it is most likely that he presented information to the Board of Directors, who actually decided on the outcome.  Menken is just the messenger of the verdict, and he brought with him a team of Oscorp Security to enact it.